# Unable to #import<Foundation/NSXMLDocument.h>

Tags: objective-c, ios, import, nsxmldocument

I am going to use `NSXMLElement` in my project, so I tried to

```
#import <Foundation/NSXMLDocument.h>
```

but it gives an error: "No such file or directory." How can I include this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

NSXMLDocument is an OS X only class

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSXMLDocument_Class/Reference/Reference.html

You cant use it in iOS.

Answer (score 0):

You should include Foundation/Foundation.h which pulls in everything you need.  If you created the project not from one of Apple's Objective-C templates, you'll need to make sure that the Foundation framework is referenced by it.

Comment: @Aravindhanarvi: Sorry about this, but I didn't realise this was an iphone question.  In fact (as Warren says) the classes you want aren't available on the iPhone.

Answer (score 0):

On iOS you can use [NSXMLParser](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSXMLParser_Class/Reference/Reference.html).